# Mathematical disciplines with high thresholds

Tags: soft-question, education, big-list, visualization, big-picture

Are there mathematical disciplines that are extremely inaccessible, with very high thresholds even for those who have the necessary prerequisites?

Number theory and graph theory, for example, are very complicated in themselves, but everyone can still form an idea of ​​what it's all about. Also, category theory is relatively easy to understand, although the definitions and methods are very abstract.

General topology is more abstract from scratch and many get lost (just unnecessary). Those who practice the methods of analysis understand the importance of open sets, but it is not easy to develop a proper intuition.

Many people have problems with homological algebra, in my opinion because they misunderstand the diagrams: large charts do not mean more difficult problems, but more information; the diagram is just a very efficient way to display information that facilitates problem solving with a few standard methods.

However, I ask for very inaccessible disciplines which are fundamentally difficult to understand even for mathematicians with prior knowledge.

Comment: Ever heard of "Inter-universal Teichmüller theory"?

Comment: @sigmabe Aaahh. I was just about to say that. You beat be me to it ;). - other than that: I personally find higher category theory signficantly harder to get into than category theory. - what about intuitonistic mathematics (e.g. smooth infinitesimal analysis) or inconsistent mathematics? Also Surreal analysis...

Comment: @Stefan I don't think Surreal anything is a great candidate. The Surreals are just a number line with everything filled in, and facts are pretty accessible to those with relevant background knowledge.

Comment: @MarkS. I vaguely remembered some issue with the existence of integrals; anyway I think this came from the conclusion of this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.7392v1.pdf

Comment: I think that the "inaccessibility" is related to history, that is, many common disciplines of math were inaccessible in the past, due to lack of understanding (by example anything related to complex numbers in the beginning of the theory). So I think it depends about the way someone approach to a theory or topic it can be more or less inaccessible, and at the same time this is related to the historic moment were the topic fit. Nowadays, to me, some topics of number/combinatorics theory, in a big degree, is problematic or it lacks "beauty", that is, understandability.

Comment: @sigmabe: Yes, I've heard about Shinichi Mochizuki and his "Inter-universal Teichmüller theory" but I didn't know it had been "verified".

Comment: @Masacroso: yes the accessibility is normally due to a development, the way the theory has been presented - a question of pedagogics. Never the less, the development could be faster or slower.

Comment: @MarkS. The basic construction of the Surreals is pretty accessible with the appropriate background, however the question of what integration means in $N_0$ is still not well understood after ~45 years of effort in the field. I think this qualifies as an 'inaccessible discipline', although it is one that is currently inaccessible to everyone.

Comment: @Alec, I see then. I was thinking of inaccessible as "agreed upon/considered known to a handful of experts", rather than inaccessible because we haven't yet found/agreed upon the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are two examples by changing our underlying logic (perhaps someone else can comment on "Inter-universal Teichmüller theory" since I know nothing about it except that it is hard to get into):

- **constructive and intuitonistic mathematics**: is probably not easy to get into for the average mathematician, since there are many possible pitfalls. Just look at the notion of "finite set". There are 5 different notions given on [the nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/finite+set) that are all equivalent in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ but generally not equivalent in constructive mathematics. Parts of measure theory and topology get extra complicated since the classical notions start to "fall apart" (c.f. [Cheng spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cheng+space) and [locales](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locale)). The situation gets even spicier if we start to contradict the law of excluded middle (c.f. 
  [smooth infinitesimal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_infinitesimal_analysis)).
- **inconsistent / paraconsistent mathematics**: this even much more obscure than constructive mathematics. The basic idea is the if we get rid of *ex falso quodlibet* then we are allowed to talk about contradictory statements without our logic becoming trivial (note that this usually stops the disjunctive syllogism from working). You can try to [do mathematics in this setting](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-inconsistent/). If I'm not mistaken: one motivation is to talk about "real numbers" $\varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon > 0$ *and* $\varepsilon = 0$.

Comment: I teach Math also for Computer Scientists. Bachelor and Master. Computational algebraic geometry can be rather accessible but sheaves and newer theory of AG are not.

Comment: @Wuestenfux: sheaves beats me. If I'm to old for such new ideas or if the pedagogic is bad - I don't know. I got no intuition at all and I wonder if anybody so far has made the theory enough intuitive?

Comment: Same for me. For engineers sheaves are too hard. As you said intuition is missing.

Comment: Sorry about the bounty, I thought it would be awarded automatically.

Comment: @Lehs No worries. I'm sure you hoped for other answers as well.